# Doctrine 2.1: how to set "cascade: persist" using yaml

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I get an error when I try to do

```
$b = new B();
$a->addB($b);
$entityManager->persist($a);
```

because I first need to persist $b, however I cannot do this, so I need to set cascade: persist I believe. I just cannot find in documentation how to do this using yaml schema.
[Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/basic-mapping.html) does not cover this part ( I tried in other places in documentation as well)

Cheers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works for me

```
oneToMany:
    products:
      targetEntity: Name
      mappedBy: product
      cascade: ["persist"]
```

Comment: Link to the Doctrine documentation:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Answer (score 0):

If class A has an association, say, one-to-many to B, and the ArrayCollection variable in A is called $bcollection, then the YAML section for cascade={"persist"} would look like this:

```
oneToMany:
    bcollection:
      targetEntity: Entities\B
      cascade
        - persist
      mappedBy: contact
      inversedBy: null
      orphanRemoval: false
      orderBy: null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried `cascade: ["persist"]` and still not working here's why.

As of 2016-08-28, I am using the latest version of doctrine at this time.
The doctrine `persist` is not working anymore because it is **removed**.

The main reason is you should not be changing the *primary key* of the connected table. And if you did, then why?

That is the reason the `cascade persist` is removed in YML Doctrine 2.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/fdL7sgtjRM0