# Doctrine 2 entities relationships: cascade merging

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-3.4

I manage complex entities, with multiple and different relationships with other entities, which themselves are linked to multiple other entities sometime.

I am making an edit form, and would like to avoid having to code manually different Doctrine 2 queries to udpate every entity linked to the modified entity.

---

Is it possible to cascade merge entities in Doctrine 2 ? By that, I mean modifying an entity and its linked entities (**oneToMany**, **ManyToMany**... relationships) and then applying the changes to the entity and the linked entities in cascade.

If not, what is the 'clean' way to apply modifications to all the concerned entities ? Does it need to be manually done, by calling merge or update on every entity ?

Comment: @Dragos yes I did, and it works when creating a new entity with linked entities correctly, by using persist. But it does not work when calling merge with a modified existing entity. When doing so, the main entity gets modified correctly but the modifications made to the linked entities are totally ignored.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my first comment because I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39187411/2162347) answer

Comment: @Dragos no problem

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are working on Symfony (correct me if I'm wrong).

On symfony forms, when you are working with underlying objects, you sometimes need to put 'by_reference' option to 'false' in order to correctly handle the underlying modified objects.

See that : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#by-reference

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I am working on symfony but I use it as a rest api with an angular front. I don't use symfony forms.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably the problem has nothing to do with symfony but more with your doctrine relationships. You should check your associations as changes made only to the inverse side of an association are ignored by doctrine. Refer to the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts).

Comment: My relationships are bidirectionals and work correctly for creating a new entity, but not when modifying an existing one using persist / merge

Comment: Yes that sounds totally like an owning-inverse side problem as I referred above. I suggest to check if you are making changes only in the inverse side of the association.